# Need to extend import file size of database in mysql that is running on docker

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, file-upload, mysqlimport

I want to import 14 GB database file in `mysql:5.7` which is running on Docker. But couldn't import the large database.

I have tried to add the max upload size with 16GB in `docker-compose.yml` file, but when I go to import, it shows request entity is too large.

Now I want to expect to you to give me guideline to extend the max upload file size.

Comment: Please can you say more about the "14 GB database file"? Is this just a SQL dump (text file)? How are you trying to upload these data into MySQL? Please include your current `docker-compose.yml` in the question so that it's clearer what you are trying to do.